# Reactive data table in Shiny with optional filtering

Tags: r, datatable, shiny, datatables, reactive-programming

I have a double problem creating a simple Shiny app. I know this topic was covered in several other questions, but having studied them, I havent found a question that would fully cover my problems.

I want to render mtcars table (full 32 rows as a default option) and then I want to apply a reactive filter on the number of gears with multiple selection allowed.

The following code doesnt work in a number of ways:

1. The mtcars table is not rendered unless filter on gears is set. Instead -I got an error message in the app: "Result must have length 32, not 0"
2. Choosing multiple gears levels does not add up correctly. When I select each gear number separately, the table is rendered correctly, but, lets say, when I combine to show gear number 3 and 4, I got only 10 rows return, which is incorrect.

I appreciate your help in advance.

```
 ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    mainPanel(

      selectInput("pickvalue", label = "Gears", mtcars$gear,
                  selected = NULL, multiple = T)),


      tableOutput("tableOut")

    )
  )


server <- function(input, output, session){


 gears <- reactive({
    mtcars %>%  filter(gear == input$pickvalue) %>% select(-gear)
  })

  output$tableOut<- renderTable({gears()
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server=server)
```

Comment: I believe you want `gear %in% input$pickvalue` if allowing multiple options to filter by...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to your problems are

1. Create an `if statement` when your input is `NULL` (i.e. when you first open the app) that will just spit out the dataset
2. When selecting multiple inputs, you need to use `%in%` operator

See code below:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    mainPanel(

      selectInput("pickvalue", label = "Gears", unique(mtcars$gear),
                  selected = NULL, multiple = T)),


    tableOutput("tableOut")

  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session){


  gears <- reactive({

    dat <- mtcars

    if (!is.null(input$pickvalue)){dat <- dat %>% filter(gear %in% input$pickvalue)} 

    dat <- dat %>% select(-gear)

    return(dat)

  })

  output$tableOut<- renderTable({gears()})

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server=server)
```

Comment: Thanks! I would have incremental question concerned with updateSelectInput I guess. 

Lets assume I have additional selectInput clauses like Carb:

selectInput("pickvalue2", label = "Carb", unique(mtcars$carb),
                selected = NULL, multiple = T)),

Carb has 6 unique values, not all of them combine with 3 unique values from Gears. Would it be possible to update selectInputs reactively, so that it shows only existing combinations of Gears and Carbs and doesnt return empty rows?

Comment: Yes, you would need to put the second selectInput in the server side using uiOutput/renderUI and then filter the choices based on input$pickvalue's selection

Comment: Thanks, but which one would be the 'second', cause I can start filtering either with Carb or Gears in that case

Comment: If you want either Carb or Gears to be the first filter, then you'll have to put them both inside the server and use some observes to catch when using the other filter. That gets much more complicated but do-able

Comment: Oh I see, I have never implemented any observers/actions, that seems a little too much. Do you perhaps have some good tutorial where I could learn that?

Comment: This is a great website: https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/  Also, if the answer above solves your question, please mark it as correct so other people know it's right.